# Can I use "I wouldn't be good company" for a video call?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request

Let's say I am supposed to go out with my friends but I am feeling down so I want to cancel, explaining:

> Sorry lads, I wouldn't be much company today.

Can I say the same thing when I am supposed to call someone on Skype for example or is there a better phrase? I am unsure simply because the word "company" feels like it should be used only for physical meetings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to be good company is used when  you are in or going to be in the presence of people.

I would not use it about a Skype call.  You are not really in the presence of people.

I wouldn't be much fun today. For example.